# FitBit API "Get Activity TCX" Not Returning The Expected Content (Response Code 200)

Tags: python, api, fitbit

I have tried for hours getting the content of the .tcx file via the fitbit api. But, with no luck. I have no issue getting "Heartrate-, Sleep- og Profile data i.e.". Maybe I can't get the .tcx data simply because it's .tcx format, and not .json format?

According to the FitBit Developer Reference:

- "Response Code 200 = A successful request."
- Response should be in an XML format

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :-)

```
import requests
import json

# Connect to API using Implicit Grant Flow
access_token = 'eyJhbGciOXXXXI1NiJ9.eyJhdWXiOiIyMXXXU0giLCJzdWIiOiI0WU5HM1EiLFFUEOWMiOiJGaXRiaXQXXXeXAiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZWXiLCJzY29wZXMiOiJ3584WF3BybyB3bnV0IHdzbGUgd3dXXXXc29jIHdhY3Qgd3NlXCB3bG9jIiwiZXXXXjoxNjQxNXXXMDc1LCJpYXQiOjE2XXXXXDc0ODR9.cuioifVTTG1ThUWXXAQH1Y816dTnWXXXkfsyANc-Qc'

# Get TCX Data
def get_activity_tcx():
    logid = '44962596407'
    url = f'https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/{logid}.tcx?'
    header = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    return response

get_activity_tcx())
```

##### Output

```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: You probably don't want to share your private API access token.

Comment: That being said, do you know how to inspect the contents of a response object? Just printing the response object itself is not enough, as you've already seen. Try `response.text` or `response.content` if you want bytes.

Comment: Hi Paul, No, i didnt know about the response.text or response.content... But it worked, thanks alot! :-)... Oh, and the Access token in the question isnt real, its just a dummy token.